# Make component a property so that I can access its methods

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Currently creating a TypeScript/React app and I've run into an issue. What I want to do is store a component as a property in a another component, so that I can access it's methods and properties directly (because I need to get to it's children's methods). Basically what I want to do is something like this:

```
class FooContainer extends React.component<FooContainerProps,FooContainerState> {
    bar: Bar;

    constructor(props: FooContainerProps) {
        super(props);
        this.bar = new Barcontainer({bar_prop1: asdf, ...});
    }
    aThing() {
        this.bar.doSomething();
    }

    render() {
        return <Foo bar={this.bar} />;
    }
}

class Foo extends React.component<FooProps,undefined> {
    render() {
        return ( ... {this.props.bar} ...);
    }
}

class BarContainer extends React.component<BarContainerProps,BarcontainerState>{
    doSomething() {
    }
    render() {
        return <div>...</div>;
}
```

I also need bar to update whenever I set the state of foo, since bar's props rely on foo's state. Any ideas?

Edit: Thank you very much for the help. Using what was given, I found a way to make it so that the Component won't have any object properties and so it now looks like this:

```
class FooContainer extends React.component<FooContainerProps,FooContainerState> {
    bar: Bar;

    registerBar(bar: Bar) {
        this.bar = Bar;
    }

    aThing() {
        this.bar.doSomething();
    }

    render() {
        return <Foo
            registerBar={this.registerBar.bind(this)}
            bar={this.bar} />;
    }
}

class Foo extends React.component<FooProps,undefined> {
    render() {
        return ( 
            ... 
            <Bar ref={(el) => {this.props.registerBar(el)}} />
            ...
        );
    }
}

class BarContainer extends React.component<BarContainerProps,BarcontainerState>{
    doSomething() {
    }

    render() {
        return <div>...</div>;
}
```

Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: Does the `Foo.render` method really just return the `this.bar.render()` result? If so then there's no reason for `Foo` to be a react component. If your real code is different then please update the question with something that will explain your scenario better.

Comment: No, that's just part of what it returns. I was trying to make a minimal example.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to accomplish. You're not supposed to pass components in the props. Props and state should only contain data with which you render the components. What's wrong with just rendering `BarContainer ` as a regular child of `Foo`? Maybe explain your what you're trying to do?

Comment: If I were to just render `BarContainer` as a child of `Foo`, how would I get access to the functions of `BarContainer` in `FooContainer`? That's the main problem.

Comment: perhaps [`this.refs`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the "react way":

```
class Foo extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    private bar: Bar;

    render() {
        return <div><Bar ref={ el => this.bar = el } /></div>
    }
}

class Bar extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
    render() {
        ...
    }
}
```

More on refs in: [Refs and the DOM](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Should Components (not containers) have a referenceable parameter from it's container? It would keep with stateless, but it seems wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What do you define as a container? What do you mean by "a referenceable parameter"?